# how can i publish my asp.net 3.5 to my local iis 7.5 of windows7?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis-7, asp.net-membership

i have created website using visual studio 2008 i think its asp.net 3.5 ... i wanna host this site to my local iis7.5 i have windows 7 professional install ..can anybody tell me hot to run this site in my local server ..

from folder C:/Inetpub

i want tutorail ... how to configure iss7.5 to use and run asp.net 3.5 with ajax website .. to my local server before i publish is to development server ..

please provide me help as soon as possible. ..thank you in advance

Comment: Here's a [blog post](http://www.iridescence.no/post/Deploying-AspNet-Sites-to-IIS7-from-Visual-Studio.aspx) you might take a look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2009/04/08/publishing-an-asp-net-web-application-in-iis.aspx)